# Change custom color font in flutter not working for spec font

Tags: flutter, fonts

I'm using this font https://www.dafont.com/pixeloid-sans.font in flutter, but can't accept custom colors, like this:

pubspec.yaml :

```
fonts:
    - family: Pixeloid Sans
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/PixeloidSans-Bold.ttf
        - asset: fonts/PixeloidSans.ttf
```

now, code:

```
       Text(
          'You have pushed the button this many times:',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5!.apply(color: Colors.amberAccent, fontFamily: "Pixeloid Sans"),
        )
```

The font changes, but color not.

Comment: Have you tried doing a `flutter clean`? Does it work when you define a style like this: `TextStyle(color: Colors.amberAccent, fontFamily: 'Pixeloid Sans')`

Comment: yes! I did a clean but doesn't resolve.

Comment: I've tried using this font myself and I have the same issue. I'm not sure if it is an issue with the font itself or the rendering of it. You should probably create an Issue on the flutter Github.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, for the same font.

It worked after converting the font from `.ttf` to `.otf`.